# Child script execution in crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron

I have a shell script which launches many different python scripts.

The shell script exports many variables, which are in turn used by the python scripts.

This is working perfectly when run in command line, but it does not work when executed in crontab.

In the cron logs, I could see the shell script working, but the python script does not seem to run.

1. Will the python scripts be able to run from the shell script in cron?
2. Will the python scripts be able to access the env variables set by the parent shell script from cron?

Comment: could you share some examples of the crontab entries and some other code so we can see how everything is being called?

Comment: Shell scripts started with cron run in the environment of `crond` not affected by shell initialization files. Thus some environment vars necessary for python to run might be missing. Redirect stderr to a file and see what shows up.

Comment: Seems like, the python script is not even executing.

Comment: Try creating a separate entry that simply does `python --version` or something. If that errs, you probably need to define `$PATH` inside your crontab properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems it's a good idea to use full qualified paths to commands in any script that's being called from cron, so as to avoid PATH and environment variable issues with the bare-bones environment that cron is called in.